# .NET PowerPacks RectangleShape flickers on form resize

Tags: .net, gdi+, powerpacks

I can do something as simple as:

1. Create a new .NET form application
2. Put a single RectangleShape onto the form
3. add the following into the InitializeComponent method in the designer code

   ```
   Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or _
       ControlStyles.UserPaint Or _
       ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
   Me.UpdateStyles()
   ```
4. Run the program
5. Resize the form
6. Watch angrily as the rectangle flickers

Is it possible to get rid of this? Or is the ShapeContainer internally flawed and I need to find a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly flawed.  It uses its own window that's overlaid onto the form with the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style turned on.  That style makes it invisible, but also prevents any kind of double-buffering from working properly.  Double-buffering the form has no effect, wrong window.

It is otherwise a rather expensive way to draw shapes.  The cheap and flicker-free way is using e.Graphics.FillRectangle() in the form's OnPaint() override or Paint event handler.

Comment: Alright, well test it yourself - but I see quite the difference when double buffering the form.  It still flickers with the form double buffered, but if you follow my steps - toggling the double buffer between runs - you should notice it.  With that aside, thanks for your affirmation that the tool is flawed.  I will use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the ShapeContainer but when ever I do custom graphics like that, I create a subclass for a Panel and in the constructor of my subclass I set DoubleBuffered to true.

More specific code example [here](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/04/double-buffering-with-panel-to-avoid.html).

Comment: Yeah, sadly the ShapeContainer class is notinheritable.  That was my first attempt as well: [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553065/net-powerpacks-shapecontrol-any-way-to-double-buffer)